# Textarea to expand similar to Medium Editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I noticed that the Textarea of the [Medium](https://medium.com/new-story) editor does not have a scroll bar that expands as text is typed and also expands the entire webpage instead of having a fixed height.

**Demo:**

**Before typing:**

[image: The Textarea does not have a scroll bar]

**After typing:**

[image]

Notice that the text area expanded the entire browser webpage instead of expanding the textarea only.

**How do I get this done in CSS?**

This is what I have right now:

```
.postbox-desc-input{
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT: HTML Code**

```
<div id="pb-expan-postbox">
      <textarea id="pb-descbox" placeholder="Type your Text here" class="postbox-desc-input"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `overflow: scroll;` property to `.postbox-desc-input` css class, Or please add your html code also in your post

Comment: they use `contenteditable="true"` on a div element for what it's worth

Comment: @Russell That forces a Horizontal and Vertical Scrolls. I'm looking to expand the **webpage's** height when the user presses the 'enter' key. Also to disable the textarea's scrollbars

Comment: `overflow: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;`
You may also need to add for IE8:

`-ms-overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: @scunliffe would that work? I found something interesting. I inspected their editor and I noticed that <p> elements are dynamically generated upon every 'enter' key stroke! That could work too

Comment: @Russell Thanks Russel but still the Text area doesn't expand the **webpage's height** instead of its own height :/

Comment: Can you please add your html code

Comment: Your Medium link didn't take me to the page you show in you screen shots, could you update it?  And please add all of you code!

Comment: @JeffArries Very sorry mate, Medium doesn't allow us to see that Text editor unless we login apparently. Anyway, what it does is.. the text area forces the browser's webpage elements to move down when I press the enter key. Basically overriding the browser's scroll

Comment: No problem!  So your basically asking someone to write it from scratch for you?

Comment: @JeffArries No sir! haha, I just needed to know if anybody knew an alternative to that or any already implemented solutions

Comment: Ok.  Shouldn't the page automatically resize when more (i.e. `<p>`) elements are put there?

Comment: Put `height=80%` instead of `height: 100%;` in css class .postbox-desc-input

Comment: @JeffArries Do you have any idea how it works? As in, how they generate <p>? I do have an idea how to generate DOM elements in JS but I'm very confused how and where they placed their text area. Does it generate <p> elements below the textarea, etc.

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I don't know JavaScript very well, my guess would be (without seeing the real thing myself) is that they place the `<p>`'s after the text area, but as I said, I have no idea. Sorry!  P.S. I like your username!

Comment: @JeffArries Thanks for taking the time Jeff! :) And thanks for the compliment! #WelcomeBackScottKelly :D

Comment: You must need to set height of textarea in `px` and then add this code in css ` overflow-y: auto; `